# Marshalling a Spring Data Jpa Projection in a rest endpoint to xml produces strange tags

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jaxb

When marshalling a spring data jpa projection, the xml structure is invalid. The proxy is displayed as a root xml tag, not the projection interface class name. The JSON output however is fine, but the rest client on the external system does not understand json.

The entity looks like this example - the real entity is more complicated:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String city;
    private int age;
    // getters, setters, ...
}
```

The projection interface looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name = "user-short")
public interface UserShort {
    String getName();
    String getCity();
}
```

The response from the rest endpoint shows (we need application/xml):

```
<.Proxy253>
  <name>Alexander</name>
  <city>Alexandria</city>
</.Proxy253>
```

The number in the proxy tag is changing. I would expect a root tag with the name of the interface or the `@XmlRootElement(name = "user-short")` annotation like this:

```
<user-short>
  <name>Alexander</name>
  <city>Alexandria</city>
</user-short>
```

We are using a interface-based Spring Data JPA projection in our project. Now we want to use it in a REST endpoint, without exposed repositories. So we can't use Spring Data Rest projections. Due to nested projections, we can't use class-based projections either. The JSON output looks like expected, but the xml output writes the proxy class as the root tag. And all XML-Annotations are ignored ( enums don't get converted to ordinals etc. ).

In a debugger when I open the variable of the interface type `UserShort` I see a instance of type `com.sun.proxy.Proxy`, some reflection stuff. There is no implementation of `UserShort`.

What is the prefered way to tell the marshaller to use the information from the interface and not the reflection stuff in spring boot?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try is not supported by the JAXB spec:

> The mapping  of existing Java  interfaces to schema
>   constructs  is  not supported. Since  an  existing class 
>   can implement multiple interfaces, there is no obvious mapping of  existing interfaces to XML schema constructs.

Sou you should use Class-based Projections (DTOs) on Spring Data